# Pass @lang as @section parameter in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, multilingual, laravel-blade

I am working on a Multi Lingual Application in Laravel 5.4

template.blade.php

```
<title>@yield('title')</title>
```

Then in other pages, I am trying to set the tile dyamically based on user locale. It throws error when I try to use the following:

```
@section('title',{{ __("dashboard") }})
```

or

```
@section('title', @lang("dashboard"))
```

This is the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'
```

Can any one tell how to pass `@lang` or `__('')` as paramater in a `@section()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you have as a parameter is supposedly php. Therefore, when you put @lang or {{}}, it will open php tags inside already opened php tags.
Therefore, what you can do is just put __() without the brackets. Just like that :

```
@section('title', __('dashboard'))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `trans` instead of `lang` decorators :

```
@section('title', trans("dashboard"))
```

**Or**

You can also use `__` function like this :

```
@section('title', __("dashboard"))
```

You don't need to use `{{}}` as you are not using it inside another directive.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `@section` does not provide an explicit parameter passing.

BUT, what you want is to pass the parameters to the containing template, not to the yield, so in the start of the blade:

```
@extends('my_parent',['my_parameter'=>'my_value'])
```